# How does symfony know what is the type of this object got from form?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I'm using symfony 2.8 with doctrine (and still learning as you will see).

I have this controller in which I create some form and render it.
I don't understand how symfony could possibly know what is the type of the $contract object below.
However those $contract objects end up in my database in the contract table so there must be something (magic?) I don't understand going on.

```
class MyContractsController extends BaseController
{
    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(MultiNewType::class)->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            foreach ($form->getData()['contracts'] as $contract) {
                $em->persist($contract);
            }
            $em->flush();
            return $this->validResponse();
        }
        return $this->renderModalFormResponse($form, array(
            'formTemplate' => 'MyBundle:Form:Contract/multiNew.html.twig'
        ));
    }
```

Below the MultiNewType file in which I don't see anything related to contract.

```
class MultiNewType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('contracts', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new NewInlineType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'delete_empty' => true,
            'label' => false
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contractMultiNew';
    }
}
```

And the NewInlineType in which I see all the fields of the contract table, but can't see anywhere the contract :

```
class NewInlineType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('foo', 'bar', array(
                'label' => false,
                'class' => 'MyBundle:MyClass',
            ))
            ->add('format', FormatType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
            ))
            ->add('version', VersionType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
            ))
            ->add('debut', 'datePicker', array(
                'label' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Début'
            ))
            ->add('fin', 'datePicker', array(
                'label' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Fin'
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contractNew';
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'contractEdit';
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: it should be the `MyBundle:MyClass` but you should replace it to your Entitys fcn, like `App\Entities\Contract\`

Comment: The parent form type (which has method  `getName()` returning `'contractEdit'`) should have a `public function configureOptions()`  that sets the default `data_class` option value, or it has a parent form that does.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible or not but maybe the data_class is configured in src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

Comment: Are you sure the actual NewInlineType has add('foo', 'bar', array( ?  Using bar as a type makes no sense.  I'm guessing your data_class is defined in the 'bar' type.

Comment: @ArleighHix I'm pretty sure you got it, the `configureOptions()` setting the `Contract` class is in the `Contract/EditType.php` class !! Thank you so much :) do you want to post an anwer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `NewInlineType` has a parent form as indicated by the `getParent()` method.
The parent form in this case will return `'contractEdit'` from it's `getName()` method.
In the parent (or possibly grand-parent) form you should find something like the following:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Contract;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

// ...
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Contract::class,
    ));
}
```

That pretty much does what it says; setting the default `data_class` option to your Contract class name.